# MongoDB Aggregation using java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using *GroupOperation* in java to group a field and count the value but I am not getting the desired result.

I am using Mongo Operation to connect with MongoDB using Java. I am able to group on the basis of field "company" but the count remains 0 always. I am not able to figure out the reason for this.

```
GroupOperation 
group=Aggregation.group("company").sum("company").as("count");
    Aggregation aggregation=Aggregation.newAggregation(group);
    AggregationResults<ResultMap> orderAggregate = 
mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation,EmpDesc.class,ResultMap.class);

orderAggregate.getMappedResults().forEach(s->System.out.println("^^ 
"+s.toString()));
```

Always getting:

```
 ResultMap [company=ABC, count=0]
 ResultMap [company=XYZ, count=0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It Should be

```
Aggregation.group("company").count().as("count");
```